# Alternatives for textbox and flowdocument for displaying testscript code in C# application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create an windows application that opens a test script and displays the contents of testscript (python script) on application's Mainwindow.xaml . I am a newbie to WPF. I tried using textbox and flowdocument reader. But the displayed script does not look good. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What does your xaml look like? How does it "not look good"? If you are just wanting to display the contents, you can easily do it with a multiline TextBox, or you can just use a TextBlock (basically a label).

Comment: I want it look like the code we write in a some fancy text editor. For now the xaml only has a maingrid and textbox.

Comment: With syntax highlighting and the like? That would require a custom control that has syntax highlighting capabilities built-in. It's definitely not something you'll want to try to tackle. Even with WinForms, I had used one someone wrote using a RichTextBox, and I had tinkered with using the SharpDevelop editor that can accept custom syntax definitions.

Comment: Okay thanks I will go with multiline textbox. That should be sufficient for my application.